# Get IDs of deleted documents in firestore

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-admin-sdk

I have a big collection with several thousand documents. These documents have subcollections with documents inside. Now I deleted a lot of the documents on the highest level.

Structure:
`MyCollection => MyDocument => MySubcollection => MySubdocument`

Now I realized, that the files are deleted (not showing up in any query) but the subcollections and their documents still exist. Now I am not sure how I can delete them as well, as I don't know the ID's of my deleted documents.

When I would try to find out the ID's by just sending a query to my collection to read all documents, the deleted ones are (by design) not included anymore. So how can I figure out their IDs now to delete their subcollections?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It all depends on your exact goal.*

If you want to delete **ALL** the docs in the `MyCollection` collection, including **ALL** the documents in **ALL** the sub-collection, you can use the Firebase CLI with the following command:

```
firebase firestore:delete MyCollection -r
```

Do `firebase firestore:delete --help` for more options.

Of course, this can only be done by an Owner of your Firebase project.

---

If you want to allow **other users** to do the same thing from the front-end (i.e. ALL the docs, including ALL the sub-collections), you can use the technique detailed in the ["Delete data with a Callable Cloud Function" section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections) in the doc.

As explained in this doc:

> You can take advantage of the `firestore:delete` command in the Firebase Command Line Interface (CLI). You can import any function of the Firebase CLI into your Node.js application using the `firebase-tools` package.
>
> The Firebase CLI uses the Cloud Firestore REST API to find all documents under the specified path and delete them individually. This implementation requires no knowledge of your app's specific data hierarchy and will even find and delete "orphaned" documents that no longer have a parent.

---

If you want to delete **ONLY a subset of the documents** in the `MyCollection` collection together with the documents in the sub-collection, you can use the same methods as above, with the path to the documents, e.g.:

```
firestore:delete MyCollection/MyDocument -r
```

---

Finally, if your problem is that you have already deleted "parent" documents and you don't know how to delete the documents in the (orphan) sub-collections (since you don't know the ID of the parent), you could use a Collection Group query to query all the `MySubcollection` subcollections and detect if the parent document exists or not. The following code, in JavaScript, would do the trick.

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const parentDocReferences = [];
  const deletedParentDocIds = [];

  db.collectionGroup('MySubcollection')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id);
        console.log(doc.ref.parent.parent.path);
        parentDocReferences.push(db.doc(doc.ref.parent.parent.path).get());
      });
      return Promise.all(parentDocReferences);
    })
    .then((docSnapshots) => {
      docSnapshots.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id);
        console.log(doc.exists);
        if (!doc.exists && deletedParentDocIds.indexOf(doc.id) === -1) {
          deletedParentDocIds.push(doc.id);
        }
      });
      
      // Use the deletedParentDocIds array
      // For example, get all orphan subcollections reference in order to delete all the documents in those collections (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections)
      deletedParentDocIds.forEach(docId => {
         
        const orphanSubCollectionRef = db.collection(`MyCollection/${docId}/MySubcollection`);
        // ...
        
      });
      
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! The last option is what I need. I just don't really understand why you are storing the parentDocReferences. I don't really need them, do I? The `doc.exists` refers to the parental document?

Comment: If with your question about  storing the parentDocReferences you mean "why do you do `parentDocReferences.push()`?" it is because we want to issue an undetermined number of calls to the asynchronous `get()` method, in order to get all the parent documents. We need to know when all these calls are finished, therefore we use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: `Promise.all()` "returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises. This returned promise will resolve when all of the input's promises have resolved". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This is perfect. Now I just need to implement this in Java :)